# How can I display CREDIT, DEBIT and BALANCE from two tables with SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables `PAY` and `INVO` that I want to display in one table I also to order by date

[image]

Comment: please give the proper explanation that what is de and cr?

Comment: de >>>debit>> and  cr >>>>credit

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Always good to provide sql script to create the data. When date is mentioned you need to specify the format as well to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the database is Oracle. You can use Oracle's analytic function [SUM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm) to achieve the desired result.

Here is the solution based on the data provided.

```
create table pay 
( 
    name varchar(10),
    "date" date,
    money number
);

create table invo 
( 
    name varchar(10),
    "date" date,
    invo_total number
);

insert into pay values ('mark',to_date('01012016','mmddyyyy'),100);
insert into pay values ('mark',to_date('01012017','mmddyyyy'),200);

select * from pay;
```

NAME   date            MONEY

---------- ---------        ----------

mark           01-JAN-16          100 

mark           01-JAN-17          200

```
insert into invo values ('mark',to_date('03012015','mmddyyyy'),200);
insert into invo values ('mark',to_date('02012016','mmddyyyy'),150);
insert into invo values ('mark',to_date('01022017','mmddyyyy'),200);

select * from invo;
```

NAME            date          INVO_TOTAL

----------     ---------   ----------

mark          01-MAR-15          200 

mark          01-FEB-16          150 

mark          01-FEB-17          200

```
WITH trans_dtls AS
(
    SELECT rownum rn,
       name,
       "date",
       NVL(i.invo_total,0) de,
       NVL(p.money,0) cr,
       NVL(i.invo_total,0)- NVL(p.money,0) AS curr_sum
   FROM pay p
       FULL OUTER JOIN invo i USING (name,"date")
   ORDER BY name,"date"
)
SELECT 
   td1.name, 
   td1."date",
   de,
   cr,
  SUM(td1.curr_sum) over (order by td1.name,"date") bal
FROM trans_dtls td1;
```

NAME            date                        DE                   CR                  BAL

----------     ---------    ----------     ----------     ----------

mark          01-MAR-15           200                   0                   200 

mark          01-JAN-16             0                 100                   100 

mark          01-FEB-16           150                   0                   250 

mark          01-JAN-17             0                 200                    50 

mark          01-FEB-17           200                   0                   250

Comment: i use sql sever not database  oracle

Comment: @MahmoudMagdyMousaa In SQL Server also SUM and other analytic functions are supported. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187810.aspx

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
'NVL' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @MahmoudMagdyMousaa you should be able to use ISNULL in MS SQL. http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/nvl

Comment: ok >>>>Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'USING'.

Answer (score 0):

First insert data into temp table with date wise ascending order then
Use below CTE method to get your result :

```
CREATE TABLE #Invoice(Name VARCHAR(100),_Date DATE,total INT)
CREATE TABLE #pay(Name VARCHAR(100),_PayDate DATE,_money INT)
CREATE TABLE #Balance(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),Name VARCHAR(100),_PayDate    
DATE,DE INT ,CR INT ,Bal INT)

INSERT INTO #Invoice(Name ,_Date ,total )
SELECT 'mark','03/01/2015',200 UNION ALL
SELECT 'mark','01/02/2016',150 UNION ALL
SELECT 'mark','01/02/2017',200 

INSERT INTO #pay(Name ,_PayDate ,_money )
SELECT 'mark','01/01/2016',100 UNION ALL
SELECT 'mark','01/01/2017',200 

INSERT INTO #Balance ( Name ,_PayDate ,DE , CR)
SELECT Name , _Date Date , total , 0
FROM #Invoice 
UNION ALL
SELECT Name , _PayDate  Date , 0 , _money
FROM #pay 
ORDER BY Date ASC

;WITH CTEBalence(_Id , Name ,_PayDate ,DE , CR ,bal) AS
(
  SELECT Id , Name ,_PayDate ,DE , CR , CASE WHEN DE > 0 THEN DE WHEN CR > 0         
  THEN CR END
  FROM #Balance
  WHERE Id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Id ,B.Name ,B._PayDate ,B.DE , B.CR , CASE WHEN B.DE > 0 THEN (        
  C.bal + B.DE ) WHEN B.CR > 0 THEN ( C.bal - B.CR ) END
  FROM #Balance B 
  JOIN CTEBalence C ON Id > _Id AND _Id = Id - 1
)

SELECT * FROM CTEBalence
```

Comment: i am not need insert data to third table(balance) because what if data modify in invo >>>and pay ....i want built query by two table invo and pay